# Xpath text selector on HTML Javascript Text Output

Tags: html, xpath, extractor

I am new to Xpath and currently working to extract data at below link:

https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60203330/

Xpath as below will print all text value as code in snippet.

Is there any additional to XPath can be add to extract the javascript text output var jProductData only?

```
//*[@id="mainPadding"]/script[3]/text()
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var MODELS = "Models";
    var js_fn_MAX_NO_OF_LISTS = "10";
    var js_ECOM_ENABLED = true;
    var MOST_LIKELY_IN_STOCK = "Currently in stock at";
    var PROBABLY_IN_STOCK = "Probably in stock at";
    var SMALL_CHANCE_IN_STOCK = "Small chance of being in stock at";
    var AVAILABLE_BY_ORDER = "Only available by order with delivery where delivery fees apply at";
    var NOT_IN_STOCK = "Not in stock at";
    var NOT_FOR_SALE = "Not for sale at";
    var SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = "Stock information is temporarily unavailable.<br> Please try again later.";
    var FOOD_STOCK_DATA_UNAVAILABLE = "No stock information is available for IKEA food products, please check in store.";
    var IKEA = "IKEA";
    var BRAND = "IKEA";
    var highChanceInfoBar = "/ms/img/static/stock_check_green.gif";
    var probablyInfoBar = "/ms/img/static/stock_check_yellow.gif";
    var smallChanceInfoBar = "/ms/img/static/stock_check_red.gif";
    var stockCheckChoice = "false";
    var showFoodStockDataUnavailableMsg = false;
    var jProductData = {"product":{"items":[{"custMaterials":"100 % polyester<br/>","descriptiveAttributes":{},"imperial":"Length: 71 \"<br/>Width: 71 \"<br/>Area: 34.88 sq feet<br/><br/>","catEntryId":"649380","dualCurrencies":false,"pkgInfoArr":[{"articleNumber":"60203330","pkgInfo":[{"heightImp":"¾ &#34;","weightImp":"15 oz","weightMet":"0.43 kg","widthImp":"5 &#34;","widthMet":"13 cm","quantity":"1","consumerPackNo":1,"lengthImp":"9 ¾ &#34;","lengthMet":"25 cm","heightMet":"2 cm"}]}],"type":"Shower curtain","reqAssembly":false,"soldSeparately":"","name":"SALTGRUND","bti":false,"attachments":[],"partNumber":"60203330","avg_rating":"5","validDesign":["gray"],"goodToKnowPIP":"To be completed with shower curtain rings and a shower curtain rod.<br/>","techInfoArr":[],"careInst":"Machine wash warm, normal cycle.<br/>Do not bleach.<br/>Do not tumble dry.<br/>Iron low.<br/>To retain water repellence, iron after washing.<br/>Do not dry clean.<br/>","extendedContext":[{"articleNumber":"60203330","extendedContext":[{"avg_rating":"5","rating_count":"3","gprAvgRating":"5","gprRatingCount":"3"}]}],"designer":"Emma Jones","nopackages":"1","goodToKnow":"To be completed with shower curtain rings and a shower curtain rod.<br/>","url":"/us/en/catalog/products/60203330/","packagePopupUrl":"/us/en/catalog/packagepopup/60203330/","availabilityUrl":"/us/en/catalog/availability/60203330/","environment":"No perfluorinated chemicals (e.g. PFOS, PFOA, PFOSA) are used to make this product water repellent. As perfluorinated chemicals are non-degradable, it\u2019s better for you and the environment to avoid them.<br/>The material in this product MAY BE recyclable. Please check the recycling rules in your community and if recycling facilities exist in your area.<br/>Non-chlorine bleach.<br/>No optical brightener has been used.<br/>","rating_count":"3","color":"gray","custBenefit":"<cbs><cb><t>Two-sided woven polyester which gives a soft fall and a decorative pattern on both sides.<\/t><\/cb><cb><t>Densely-woven polyester fabric with water-repellent coating.<\/t><\/cb><\/cbs>","metric":"Length: 180 cm<br/>Width: 180 cm<br/>Area: 3.24 m²<br/><br/>","buyable":true,"prices":{"comparisonPriceExists":false,"hasTemporaryFamilyOffer":false,"hasFamilyPrice":false,"usesUnitPriceMeasure":false,"isUnitPricePrimary":false,"normal":{"priceNormal":{"priceExclVat":"$14.99","value":"$14.99","rawPrice":14.99},"priceNormalDual":{},"priceNormalPerUnit":{"unit":""}},"hasEcoFee":false,"enablenlpinterval":0,"hasPrfCharge":false},"images":{"zoom":["/PIAimages/0307519_PE427662_S5.JPG","/PIAimages/0406033_PE566947_S5.JPG","/PIAimages/0406724_PE567270_S5.JPG"],"normal":["/PIAimages/0307519_PE427662_S3.JPG","/PIAimages/0406033_PE566947_S3.JPG","/PIAimages/0406724_PE567270_S3.JPG"],"thumb":["/PIAimages/0307519_PE427662_S2.JPG"],"small":["/PIAimages/0307519_PE427662_S1.JPG"],"large":["/us/en/images/products/saltgrund-shower-curtain-gray__0307519_PE427662_S4.JPG","/us/en/images/products/saltgrund-shower-curtain-gray__0406033_PE566947_S4.JPG","/us/en/images/products/saltgrund-shower-curtain-gray__0406724_PE567270_S4.JPG"]},"californiaTitle20Product":false}],"catEntryId":"3260697","attributes":[{"id":"8556332","name":"color","type":"00018"},{"id":"8556333","name":"size","type":"00019"}],"partNumber":"25464 [GENERICPRODUCT]"}};    
    var jsonProduct = jProductData.product; 
    var jCatEntryId = jsonProduct.catEntryId;
    var jPartNumber = jsonProduct.partNumber;
    var storeBaseURL = "/us/en/store/";
    var PD_txt_bvDown = "We’re having some technical problems and are working on a solution. Sorry for the inconvenience.";
    var weee_lessPrf = "Less PRF ";
    var weee_prf = "PRF";
    var packageText = "Show dimensions, weight and article numbers";    
    var singlePackage = "Package";
        var multiplePackage = "Packages";
    var showAll = "Show all";
    var showLess = "Show less"; 
    var readMore = "Read more";
    var pricePerPackage = "Price/pk";
    var pricePer = "Price per";
    var ikeaFamily ="IKEA FAMILY member price"; 
    var ikeaRegular ="Regular price"; 
         var storeId="12";
         var langId="-1";     
    var currentItem = "60203330";
    var localeJs = "en_US";
    var width = "Width:";
    var articleNo = "Article Number:"
    var height = "Height:";
    var length = "Length:"
    var weight = "Weight:"
    var diameter = "Diameter:"
    var quantity = "Quantity:";
    var packages = "Packages";
    var widthTitle = "Width";
    var articleNoTitle = "Article Number"
    var heightTitle = "Height";
    var lengthTitle = "Length"
    var weightTitle = "Weight"
    var diameterTitle = "Diameter"    
    var packageMeasures = "Package measurement &amp; weight"
    var cm = "cm";
    var kg = "kg";
    var californiaLegalText = "In compliance with California Title 20 regulations, product prices and features may vary in the state of California.";
    var californiaUrlText = "Please see your local store for details";
    var californiaUrlRef = "http://info.ikea-usa.com/StoreLocator/StoreLocator.aspx";
    var californiaMoreInfo = "More information";
    var unitPriceTxt = "Unit price"
    var displayManySameProduct = "false";
    var moreText = "more";
                   var smallNewImg = '/ms/en_US/img/icons/new_small.gif';
                  var newImg = '/ms/en_US/img/icons/new_large.gif';
                  var newImgAlt = 'NEW';
                   
                   var nlpImg = '/ms//img/nlp/en_US/nlp_04.png';
                   var nlpPopupImgSrc = '/ms//img/nlp/en_US/nlp_02.png';
                   var nlpImgAlt = 'New Lower Price';
                   var assemblyInstructions = 'Assembly instructions';
                   var article = "Article";
    var pdf = "PDF";
    var download = "Download";
    var assemblyProdInfo = "Download assembly instructions.";
    var notice = "Please note that the stock can be different if checked outside of";
    var storehours = "store opening hours";
    var invalidDIFAttr = "[00019, 00033, 00029, 13622, 00028]";
    var moreProdBaseUrl = "/us/en/iows/catalog/products/";
    var packageHeader = "Package measurements and weight"

    var sscCatalogId = "";
    var sscCategory = "";
    var simsCategory = "18908";
    var simsCatalogId = "departments";
    var depthInFunctionCategory = "";
    
    var itemProperties = new Array("name","type","productTypeProdInfo" ,"itemNumber","FAcode");
    var productDetails = new Array("packageInfo","nopackages","custMaterials","imperial","metric","careInst","goodToKnowPIP","environment","custBenefit","designer","salesArg","downloadAssembly","downloadAssemblyProdInfo","designerThoughts","lowestPrice","soldSeparately");
    var priceProperties = new Array("price1", "price5" , "price6" ,"price1perunit","storeformatpieces","storeformatpieces2","price2","packUnitPrice","packUnitPrice2","packUnitPrice5","packUnitPrice6","prfCharge","ecoFee","priceProdInfo","troPrice","familystoreformatpieces","mainPriceExclVat","nlpPrice","familyDate");       
    var notAvailable = new String("(Not available)");     
    var stockCheckServiceURL = "/us/en/iows/catalog/availability/";
    var isDIFEnabled = true;
    var measFlag = "2";
    var nlpPrevPriceCrossOverEnabled = true;
    var troPrevPriceCrossOverEnabled = true;
    var troDisclaimer = "While supplies last in participating US stores. ";
    var insteadOf = "was";    
    var quality ="Everyday quality"
    var energyAndResources ="Energy & Resources"
    var sustainableLifeAtHome ="Sustainable life at home"
    var peopleAndCommunication ="People & Communities"
    var material ="Material matters"
    var formDesignProcess ="Behind the design"
    var functionSolution ="Smart functions"    
    var designerThoughts ="Designer thoughts"
    var designer ="Designer:"
    var zoomText ="Click here for zoom" 
    
    var jsonRelatedProducts = {"item_60203330":{"WPP_COMPLEMENTARY_CONTAINER":[[]],"MAY_BE_COMPLETED_WITH":["23102900"]}};
    var productsBaseUrl = "/us/en/catalog/products/";
    var showWeeeRelatedData = false;    
    var viewComplementaryProdsText = "View all coordinating products";
    var mustBeCompletedTxtOne = "Remember to complete {0} with the following product";
    var mustBeCompletedTxtMany = "Remember to complete {0} with the following {1} products";
    var complementaryProdsTxt = "Coordinating Products";    
    var soldSeparatelyTxt = "&nbsp;";
    var soldSeparatelyDesc = '';
    var soldSeparatelyFlag = "false";
    var itemRelationValue = irwstatGetTrailingTagValue('IRWStats.productFindingMethod');
    var baseURL = "/us/en/catalog/products/";    
    var altImgFlag = "true";
    var zoomImageFlag = "true";
    var localPriceFlag = "false";
    var okButton = "OK"
    var notifiyError = "&nbsp;"
    var localStoreList = "209|tempe:399|burbank:162|carson:167|costa_mesa:413|covina:347|east_palo_alto:165|emeryville:166|san_diego:157|west_sacramento:064|centennial:213|new_haven:537|jacksonville:327|miami:145|orlando:207|sunrise:042|tampa:257|atlanta:170|bolingbrook:210|schaumburg:536|fishers:374|merriam:158|stoughton:152|baltimore:411|college_park:026|canton:212|twin_cities:410|st_louis:067|charlotte:154|elizabeth:409|paramus:462|las_vegas:921|brooklyn:156|long_island:511|columbus:175|west_chester:028|portland:211|conshohocken:153|pittsburgh:215|philadelphia:508|memphis:183|frisco:535|grand_prairie:379|houston:027|round_rock:103|draper:168|woodbridge:488|seattle";
    var assembly_inst_type = "ASSEMBLY_INSTRUCTIONS";
    var atchSummaryUsgTypes = ["GUARANTEE","ASSEMBLY_INSTRUCTIONS","MANUALS","SOFTWARE_DOWNLOADS","DEC_OF_CONFORMITY"];
    var attachmentHeadline = "Instructions & other documents";
    var attachmentDocumentsTxt = "Downloads for this product:";
    var attachmentDownloads = "Downloads";
    var attachmentDisclaimer = "Only the latest version of the documents is available for download. This means that there maybe a difference in this version and the printed version.";
    var faqHeading = "FAQ & Contact Us";
    var faqContactUsHeadline = "Any questions?";
    var faqContactUsLinkTxt = "Contact Us";
    var faqContactUsLink = "https://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/contact_us/contact.html";
    var priceText = "Price/";
    var displayUnit = "";
    var showPriceExclVat = false;
    var exclVatText = "&nbsp;";
    var datePattern = "";
    uniqueUrl.updateProductMetaTag();
   </script>
```

Thanks for viewing.

Comment: Thanks to read   
 [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and properly indent your code

Comment: What tools/language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [chrome-browser-headless](/questions/tagged/chrome-browser-headless) :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60203330/');

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return window.jProductData;
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    await browser.close();

})();
```

### Output :

```
{
    "product": {
        "items": [
            {
                "custMaterials": "100 % polyester<br/>",
                "descriptiveAttributes": {},
                "imperial": "Length: 71 \"<br/>Width: 71 \"<br/>Area: 34.88 sq feet<br/><br/>",
                "catEntryId": "649380",
                "dualCurrencies": false,
                "pkgInfoArr": [
                    {
 ...
```

Comment: is it possible to build the XPath rather than using tools

Comment: You don't answer my question under your post, first reply to them

Comment: xpath can't retrieve this var alone, you need parsing with your language (and we still dunno which one you use)